# Read a large data set via fread in R but only need a subset (one variable that equals some values)

Tags: r, shell, data.table, large-data, data-cleaning

I am trying to read a large dataset (>30G) in R but my laptop only has 16G of RAM. But all I need is only a subset of this dataset. Specifically I need all the observations whose ID (there is one variable in my dataset that represents this ID) equals to some values (these values come from another dataset). If I have enough RAM, it will be natural to read the two data files first and then merge by the common ID.

With the lack in RAM, is it possible to pre-process the data file somehow using a shell command so that I can use it as an argument for `cmd` of `fread`. Or does anyone have an alternative solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the 'fread' command that you use, and the first few lines of the data file. It will make it easier to suggest a tool that is appropriate for pre-processing your data set (for the main data set, and for the dataset with the IDs)

Comment: Do you have *GNU Text Utilities* like `join`?

Comment: What OS are you using? cmd/terminal commands will differ accordingly. Alternatively, you could try loading your dataset to an sql-like server, and then access the relevant rows using a query with DBI.

Comment: An addition to @Rohit's comment, there is a package called `vroom` that might (also) help.

Comment: @dash-o Main dataset looks like: main <- data.frame("ID" = 1:5, "Age" = 21: 25, "Income" = 1001:1005) The data with IDs: people.of.interest <- data.frame("ID" = c(2, 3)). The data with IDs is small but the main dataset is over 30G.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I have looked at the documentation of ``vroom`` and it feels like a faster version of ``fread``. I can not select rows based on a variable before reading the dataset into memory.

Comment: @Rohit I am using macOS and my data is TSV files. Are you saying there is a way to transform the data into sql-like **without** loading them into memory? Also what command using query is equivalent to ``merge`` using dataframes?

Comment: Can you share few (partial) lines of the input files ?

Answer (score 3):

You can prepossess your data as described in [R Data Import/Export](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html) using the *GNU Text Utilities* `join` and `sort`.

```
#Create files to use
t1 <- tempfile() #File 1 with id and data
write.table(data.frame(id=1:5, val=5:1), t1, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
t2 <- tempfile() #File 2 with id's which should be used from File 1
write.table(c(1,3,4), t2, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

t3 <- tempfile()
t4 <- tempfile()
read.table(pipe(paste("sort -k 1b,1", t1, ">", t3, "
sort -u -k 1b,1", t2, ">", t4, "
join", t3, t4)))
#  V1 V2
#1  1  5
#2  3  3
#3  4  2
```